# Give a CCK field a non-editable value?

Tags: 6, entities

Is it possible, not only to give a CCK field a default value, but also make it non-editable by the user?

Comment: What versions (drupal/cck) are you using?

Comment: Do content editor need to be able to see the value on the edit page, or does it just need to be rendered upon pageview?

Comment: @Andrew using Drupal 6.22

Comment: @MPD it doesn't really matter either way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used jquery to do just that.

```
(function($) {

$(document).ready(function() {

// make the number field uneditable!
$('#edit-field-entry-custom-id-und-0-value').attr("disabled", "true");
}); 

}(jQuery));
```

to be safer however, in case someone disables javascript you could add this to your themes template.php

```
function YOURTHEME_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
 if($form_id == 'YOUR_FORM_ID') {
  $form['FIELD_NAME']['#disabled'] = TRUE;

  // YOU CAN UNCOMMENT THE BELOW FOR EXTRA HELPFUL DETAILS
  // GET FORM ID UNCOMMENT BELOW
  // drupal_set_message("Form ID is : " . $form_id);
  // GET ALL FORM ELEMENTS UNCOMMENT BELOW
  // drupal_set_message(dprint_r($form, TRUE));
 }
}
```

Comment: You would have to move the form_alter to a module if you have a different admin theme configured, and if content editing uses the admin theme.  Double check settings on /admin/settings/admin